# How to correctly introduce HTML tag with 2 and more classes in Idea IntelliJ?

Tags: html, intellij-idea, autocomplete

I'm using IntelliJ autocomplete for HTML feature and it is cool!. As for example when I'm trying to create a button with id and class:

```
div#myId.myClass
```

And after pressing "tab" I'm getting:

```
<div id="myId" class="myClass"></div>
```

And this is OK. But is it possible to add more than one class and than after pressing "tab" have two off them as div attribute?

ex. `<div id="myId" class="myClass myClass2 .."></div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply write

```
div#myId.myClass.myClass2
```

and press "tab". I've tested it in PhpStorm from IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

Standard Emmet syntax for creating several classes at once is

```
div#id.class1.class2.class3
```

See https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#id-and-class